# How to send an email in AWS MWAA (Apache Airflow) using EmailOperator

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am working with AWS MWAA (Apache Airflow). I want to send an email in MWAA upon completion of my pipeline.I have set the following configuration
[image]

Now when I run my dag using an Email Operator, it gives me an error.

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[2022-05-19, 11:11:21 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:154}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-05-19, 11:11:21 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:264}} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Then I changed my configuration to
[image]

It now gives the following error

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (530, b'Must issue a STARTTLS command first')
[2022-05-19, 12:22:39 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:154}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-05-19, 12:22:39 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:264}} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong or how should I configure this to send an email to a particular email address from any domain?

Answer (score 1):

Your smtp host variable is an email address and not a host.

It should be `smtp.gmail.com` not `smtp@gmail.com`

You've hopefully also changed your password as you have shared it publicly in that screenshot and anyone could use it now.